# Toggle on and off div whose ID is generated via php in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, toggle

Hoping someone can help. I am creating some custom tag functionality on a wordpress site and I am a little stuck on how to show and hide the data. Here is what I have so far:

```
 <?php global $post;
//Get terms for this taxonomy - orders by name ASC by default
$terms = get_terms('post_tag');

//Loop through each term
foreach($terms as $term):

   //Query posts by term. 
   $args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title', //As requested in comments
       'post_type'   => 'reiseberichte',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'orderby'     => 'menu_order',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($term->slug)
        )
     ));
    $tag_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    //Does tag have posts?
    if($tag_query->have_posts()):?>

                    <div class='<?php echo esc_html($term->slug);?>'><a href="#"><?php echo esc_html($term->name);?></a></div>
<?php
        //Loop through posts and display
        while($tag_query->have_posts()):$tag_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="content">
        <div class="post_content hidden-content" id='<?php echo esc_html($term->slug);?>'><?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); 
            echo the_title(); ?></div></div>
        <?php endwhile;

    endif; //End if $tag_query->have_posts
    wp_reset_postdata();
 endforeach;//Endforeach $term

?>
```

I need to do something like this to turn the divs off with the ID generated by their term slug:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(".<?php echo esc_html($term->slug);?>").click(function() {
            $("#<?php echo esc_html($term->slug);?>").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I know that is all wrong but I would appreciate any pointers. The class for the button and the ID for the containing div are both generated by `<?php echo esc_html($term->slug);?>`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What about looking up your divs by their class attribute ?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(".content").click(function() { //Look for 'content' class
            $(this).toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Not really sure how this would work. What I want to do is give each tag a class of the term slug and each containing div an id of the terms slug so when you click the relevant tag the div displays